# how to get to the cliff in outlands canyon borderlands the pre sequel

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

[image]

I'm stuck on trying to get to that part of the map. I am trying to explore all of the places and I cant get to that spot though.

Comment: Haven't played this game in a while. Could you describe that location at all? I can't recall where it is just from the overhead map.

Comment: It is near the part where you fight rabid adams. the cliff thing next to it

Comment: it might be under or above

Answer (score 1):

Having just done this myself:

> You "unlock" the "door" by accepting a quest from the board in Concordia, available after finishing the story quest with Pickle. It's a quest from Hammerlock, asking you to retrieve trasher babies.